# stripe subscription using node js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am doing stripe subscription using node js Api's when i go to subscription under dashboard its created subscription but it gives status incomplete,no payment deduction occurs
if i am doing through dashboard its create the subscription with active status

```
 id: 'sub_INTyoOKF5bt1ib',
  object: 'subscription',
  application_fee_percent: null,
  billing_cycle_anchor: 1605199862,
  billing_thresholds: null,
  cancel_at: null,
  cancel_at_period_end: false,
  canceled_at: null,
  collection_method: 'charge_automatically',
  created: 1605199862,
  current_period_end: 1605286262,
  current_period_start: 1605199862,
  customer: 'cus_INTyfeuOhg9XDC',
  days_until_due: null,
  default_payment_method: null,
  default_source: null,
  default_tax_rates: [],
  discount: null,
  ended_at: null,
  items: {
    object: 'list',
    data: [ [Object] ],
    has_more: false,
    total_count: 1,
    url: '/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_INTyoOKF5bt1ib'
  },
  latest_invoice: 'in_1Hmj0lLm4uTMGNUSyogmK9TA',
  livemode: true,
  metadata: {},
  next_pending_invoice_item_invoice: null,
  pause_collection: null,
  pending_invoice_item_interval: null,
  pending_setup_intent: null,
  pending_update: null,
  plan: {
    id: 'price_1HlYMvLm4uTMGNUSarJML52T',
    object: 'plan',
    active: true,
    aggregate_usage: null,
    amount: 100,
    amount_decimal: '100',
    billing_scheme: 'per_unit',
    created: 1604920625,
    currency: 'inr',
    interval: 'day',
    interval_count: 1,
    livemode: true,
    metadata: {},
    nickname: null,
    product: 'prod_IMGu6PI2mJbBCi',
    tiers_mode: null,
    transform_usage: null,
    trial_period_days: null,
    usage_type: 'licensed'
  },
  quantity: 1,
  schedule: null,
  start_date: 1605199862,
  status: 'incomplete',
  transfer_data: null,
  trial_end: null,
  trial_start: null
}


*********latest invoice and payment intent
 id: 'sub_INkoNdFnS5DaZR',
  object: 'subscription',
  application_fee_percent: null,
  billing_cycle_anchor: 1605262511,
  billing_thresholds: null,
  cancel_at: null,
  cancel_at_period_end: false,
  canceled_at: null,
  collection_method: 'charge_automatically',
  created: 1605262511,
  current_period_end: 1605348911,
  current_period_start: 1605262511,
  customer: 'cus_INkoPwPjgIyGbV',
  days_until_due: null,
  default_payment_method: null,
  default_source: null,
  default_tax_rates: [],
  discount: null,
  ended_at: null,
  items: {
    object: 'list',
    data: [ [Object] ],
    has_more: false,
    total_count: 1,
    url: '/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_INkoNdFnS5DaZR'
  },
  latest_invoice: {
    id: 'in_1HmzJDLm4uTMGNUSmbbqqwR7',
    object: 'invoice',
    account_country: 'IN',
    account_name: 'Walkify',
    account_tax_ids: null,
    amount_due: 100,
    amount_paid: 0,
    amount_remaining: 100,
    application_fee_amount: null,
    attempt_count: 0,
    attempted: true,
    auto_advance: true,
    billing_reason: 'subscription_create',
    charge: null,
    collection_method: 'charge_automatically',
    created: 1605262511,
    currency: 'inr',
    custom_fields: null,
    customer: 'cus_INkoPwPjgIyGbV',
    customer_address: {
      city: 'Mangaliya,Indore',
      country: 'IN',
      line1: '',
      line2: '',
      postal_code: null,
      state: 'India'
    },
    customer_email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    customer_name: 'Ravi R',
    customer_phone: '',
    customer_shipping: null,
    customer_tax_exempt: 'none',
    customer_tax_ids: [],
    default_payment_method: null,
    default_source: null,
    default_tax_rates: [],
    description: null,
    discount: null,
    discounts: [],
    due_date: null,
    ending_balance: 0,
    footer: null,
    hosted_invoice_url: 'https://invoice.stripe.com/i/acct_1HZVL5Lm4uTMGNUS/invst_INkotPj0f800RnPxEA5u8Lzw7IR6Dvy',
    invoice_pdf: 'https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_1HZVL5Lm4uTMGNUS/invst_INkotPj0f800RnPxEA5u8Lzw7IR6Dvy/pdf',
    last_finalization_error: null,
    lines: {
      object: 'list',
      data: [Array],
      has_more: false,
      total_count: 1,
      url: '/v1/invoices/in_1HmzJDLm4uTMGNUSmbbqqwR7/lines'
    },
    livemode: true,
    metadata: {},
    next_payment_attempt: null,
    number: 'A77E89AD-0001',
    paid: false,
    payment_intent: {
      id: 'pi_1HmzJDLm4uTMGNUSRu34ggsq',
      object: 'payment_intent',
      amount: 100,
      amount_capturable: 0,
      amount_received: 0,
      application: null,
      application_fee_amount: null,
      canceled_at: null,
      cancellation_reason: null,
      capture_method: 'automatic',
      charges: [Object],
      client_secret: 'pi_1HmzJDLm4uTMGNUSRu34ggsq_secret_7Sk56e79TEjpt3EQSI4a7CS5a',
      confirmation_method: 'automatic',
      created: 1605262511,
      currency: 'inr',
      customer: 'cus_INkoPwPjgIyGbV',
      description: 'Subscription creation',
      invoice: 'in_1HmzJDLm4uTMGNUSmbbqqwR7',
      last_payment_error: null,
      livemode: true,
      metadata: {},
      next_action: [Object],
      on_behalf_of: null,
      payment_method: 'pm_1HmzJBLm4uTMGNUSeROzE4C9',
      payment_method_options: [Object],
      payment_method_types: [Array],
      receipt_email: null,
      review: null,
      setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
      shipping: null,
      source: null,
      statement_descriptor: null,
      statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
      status: 'requires_action',
      transfer_data: null,
      transfer_group: null
    },
    period_end: 1605262511,
    period_start: 1605262511,
    post_payment_credit_notes_amount: 0,
    pre_payment_credit_notes_amount: 0,
    receipt_number: null,
    starting_balance: 0,
    statement_descriptor: null,
    status: 'open',
    status_transitions: {
      finalized_at: 1605262511,
      marked_uncollectible_at: null,
      paid_at: null,
      voided_at: null
    },
    subscription: 'sub_INkoNdFnS5DaZR',
    subtotal: 100,
    tax: null,
    total: 100,
    total_discount_amounts: [],
    total_tax_amounts: [],
    transfer_data: null,
    webhooks_delivered_at: 1605262511
  },
  livemode: true,
  metadata: {},
  next_pending_invoice_item_invoice: null,
  pause_collection: null,
  pending_invoice_item_interval: null,
  pending_setup_intent: null,
  pending_update: null,
  plan: {
    id: 'price_1HlYMvLm4uTMGNUSarJML52T',
    object: 'plan',
    active: true,
    aggregate_usage: null,
    amount: 100,
    amount_decimal: '100',
    billing_scheme: 'per_unit',
    created: 1604920625,
    currency: 'inr',
    interval: 'day',
    interval_count: 1,
    livemode: true,
    metadata: {},
    nickname: null,
    product: 'prod_IMGu6PI2mJbBCi',
    tiers_mode: null,
    transform_usage: null,
    trial_period_days: null,
    usage_type: 'licensed'
  },
  quantity: 1,
  schedule: null,
  start_date: 1605262511,
  status: 'incomplete',
  transfer_data: null,
  trial_end: null,
  trial_start: null
}
```

Stripe account country is india and card is also india

Comment: The payment for that invoice requires action, meaning the customer should complete 3DS before the invoice is paid and the subscription will become active. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#scenario-1. Also I would double check in which modes you're testing. As it stands, the mode could be problematic for you going forward.

Comment: You can check the situation by looking at the latest_invoice of the subscription and expanding the PaymentIntent. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#requires-action

Comment: i am using live mode with live card

Comment: i am changing in the err pls check for latest invoice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2530680/cjav-dev
@cjav-dev pls help me this out its a request

Comment: That PaymentIntent is now in cancelled state. If you follow this guide / compare it to your implementation, I'd be happy to help with any issues you encounter! https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price